# OpenGL - Indexed Draws with glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-array

I have a couple questions about how OpenGL handles these drawing operations.

1. So lets say I pass OpenGL the pointer to my vertex array. Then I can call glDrawElements with an array of indexes. It will draw the requested shapes using those indexes in the vertex array correct?
2. After that glDrawElements call could I then do another glDawElements call with another set of indexes? Would it then draw the new index array using the original vertex array?
3. Does OpenGL keep my vertex data around for the next frame when I redo all of these calls? So the the next vertex pointer call would be a lot quicker?
4. Assuming the answer to the last three questions is yes, What if I want to do this on multiple vertex arrays every frame? I'm assuming doing this on any more than 1 vertex array would cause OpenGL to drop the last used array from graphics memory and start using the new one. But in my case the vertex arrays are never going to change. So what I want to know is does opengl keep my vertex arrays around in-case next time I send it vertex data it will be the same data? If not is there a way I can optimize this to allow something like this? Basically I want to draw procedurally between the vertexes using indicies without updating the vertex data, in order to reduce overhead and speed up complicated rendering that requires constant procedurally changing shapes that will always use the vertexes from the original vertex array. Is this possible or am I just fantasizing?
5. If I'm just fantasizing about my fourth question what are some good fast ways of drawing a whole lot of polygons each frame where only a few will change? Do I always have to pass in a totally new set of vertex data for even small changes? Does it already do this anyways when the vertex data doesn't change because I notice I cant really get around the vertex pointer call each frame.
6. Feel free to totally slam any logic errors I've made in my assertions. I'm trying to learn everything I can about how opengl works and it's entirely possible my current assumptions on how it works are all wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.So lets say I pass OpenGL the pointer to my vertex array. Then I can call glDrawElements with an array of indexes. It will draw the
>   requested shapes using those indexes in the vertex array correct?

Yes.

> 2.After that glDrawElements call could I then do another glDawElements
>   call with another set of indexes? Would it then draw the new index
>   array using the original vertex array?

Yes.

> 3.Does OpenGL keep my vertex data around for the next frame when I redo
>   all of these calls? So the the next vertex pointer call would be a lot
>   quicker?

Answering that is a bit more tricky than you might. The way you ask these questions makes me to assume that uou use *client-side vertex arrays*, that is, you have some arrays in your system memory and let your vertes pointers point directly to those. In that case, the answer is `no`. The GL cannot "cache" that data in any useful way. After the draw call is finished, it must assume that you might change the data, and it would have to compare every single bit to make sure you have not changed anything.

However, client side VAs are not the only way to have VAs in the GL - actually, they are completely outdated, deprecated since GL3.0 and been *removed* from modern versions of OpenGL. The modern way of doing thins is using *Vertex Buffer Objects*, which basically are buffers which are *managed by the GL*, but manipulated by the user. Buffer objects are just a chunk of memory, but you will need special GL calls to create them, read or write or change data and so on. And the buffer object might very well not be stored in system memory, but directly in VRAM, which is very useful for static data which is used over and over again. Have a look at [the GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt), which orignially introduced that feature in 2003 and became core in GL 1.5.

> 4.Assuming the answer to the last three questions is yes, What if I want
>   to do this on multiple vertex arrays every frame? I'm assuming doing
>   this on any more than 1 vertex array would cause OpenGL to drop the
>   last used array from graphics memory and start using the new one. But
>   in my case the vertex arrays are never going to change. So what I want
>   to know is does opengl keep my vertex arrays around in-case next time
>   I send it vertex data it will be the same data? If not is there a way
>   I can optimize this to allow something like this? Basically I want to
>   draw procedurally between the vertexes using indicies without updating
>   the vertex data, in order to reduce overhead and speed up complicated
>   rendering that requires constant procedurally changing shapes that
>   will always use the vertexes from the original vertex array. Is this
>   possible or am I just fantasizing?

*VBOs* are exactly what you are looking for, here.

> 5.If I'm just fantasizing about my fourth question what are some good
>   fast ways of drawing a whole lot of polygons each frame where only a
>   few will change? Do I always have to pass in a totally new set of
>   vertex data for even small changes? Does it already do this anyways
>   when the vertex data doesn't change because I notice I cant really get
>   around the vertex pointer call each frame.

You can also update just parts of a VBO. However, it might become inefficient if you have many small parts which are randomliy distributed in your buffer, it will be more efficient to update continous (sub-)regions. But that is a topic on it's own.

Comment: Heres the trick: If I want my application to be OpenGL 1.1 compatible, is it possible to use VBOs?

Comment: @KlaytonCurran: Strictly speaking, there is nothing which would prevent a GL1.1 implementation from supporting that extension. However, it is really unlikely that anything limited to GL1.1 will do. May I ask why you are limited to GL1.1? If you really are, [display lists](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glNewList.xml) are your only alternative.

Comment: You answered everything I wanted to know cleanly and clearly and with a lot of detail. Thanks a bunch! The 1.1 question was out of curiosity mostly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No. As soon as you create a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO) it will stay in the GPU memory. Otherwise vector data needs to be re-transferred (an old method of avoiding this was Display Lists). In both cases the performance of subsequent frames should stay similar (but much better with the VBO method): you can do the VBO creation and download before rendering the first frame.
4. The VBO was introduced to provide you exactly with this functionality. Just create several VBOs. Things get messy when you need more GPU memory than available though.
5. VBO is still the answer, and see [Modifying only a specific element type of VBO buffer data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681871/modifying-only-a-specific-element-type-of-vbo-buffer-data)

Comment: Thanks! That link will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should try something called Vertex Buffer Objects. It offers the same benefits as Vertex Arrays, but you can create multiple vertex buffers and store them in "named slots". This method has much better performance as data is stored directly in Graphic Card memory.

[Here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/vertex_buffer_objects/22002/) is a good tutorial in C++ to start with.